# Asp.net MVC3 and MvcContrib Paging

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, pager, mvccontrib-grid

How do I get the paging to work on MvcContrib.grid?  I have the latest version of MvcContrib downloaded and also the following in my view.

@using MvcContrib.UI.Grid;
@using MvcContrib.Pagination;

However, I cannot seem to access Html.Pager?  Has this been changed in the latest version of MvcContrib?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pager is in `MvcContrib.UI.Pager` namespace.